# composed data tag attributes in rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I want to add a `data` attribute to a tag, say `data-prop`, I would add

```
`content_tag :div, data: {prop: "some-property"}`
```

But if I want to add `data-prop-css`

`content_tag :div, data: {prop-css: "some-property"}`

doesn't work. Is there a way do make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 content_tag :div, data: {'prop-css': "some-property"}
```